# Variable in Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, arguments

I have this code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   $("#menu-item-7285 .sub-menu li").click(function (e) {
      var str = $('a', this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
      $('a[href$=str]').closest("li").addClass("active");
      $('html,body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 800
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

This part is giving me trouble: `$('a[href$=str]')`. What is the correct way to include the str variable?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `$('a[href$=' + str + ']')`, a simple string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert it using +

```
var str = "something";
$('a[href$=' + str + ']')
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('a[href$=" ' + str + ' "]')......
```